# MySQL mysql_fetch_array

Tags: mysql, arrays, database

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT tag FROM folder WHERE nick = "'.$user.'" LIMIT 1') or die(mysql_error().":".mysql_errno());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
echo 'nothing';
}else{
echo mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
?>
```

This dont work and it display: "Array" 
Why?

Comment: what outputs are you expecting?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array (like the name suggests).  You can't just `echo` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));` instead of `echo`

Comment: and display: Array ( [0] => TEST [folder] => TEST ) so dont work

Comment: $fetResult = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $fetResult[0];